# php class clarity required please

Tags: php, class

Very basic i know, but I'm learning :)

So, I have this class:

```
class RequestPath {
private $parts = array();
    public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
            $path = (substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], -1) == "/") ? substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 0, -1) : $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        } else {
            $path = (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1) == "/") ? substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -1) : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
            $bits = explode("/", substr($path, 1));
            $parsed['id'] = array_shift($bits); $parsed[] = $parsed['id'];
            $parsed['type'] = array_shift($bits); $parsed[] = $parsed['type'];
            $parts_size = sizeof($bits); if ($parts_size % 2 != 0) {
            $parts_size -= 1;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $parts_size; $i+=2) { $parsed[$bits[$i]] = $bits[$i+1]; $parsed[] = $bits[$i+1];
        }
        if (sizeof($bits) % 2 != 0) { $parsed[] = array_pop($bits);
        }
    $this->parts = $parsed;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->parts[$key];
    } 
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->_parts[$key] = $value;
    } 
    public function __isset($key) {
        return isset($this->_parts[$key]);
    }
}
```

I'm having problems returning data from the public functions __get, __set and __isset.

What I would like to do is to run a simple if statement on __isset and then execute some code?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Did my answer help you? Remember to accept good answers.

Answer (score 3):

remove `_` in `$this->_parts`
because there is no such var in your code

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question correctly you want to do something like this ?

```
$path = new RequestPath();

if(isset($path["foo"])) {
    $x = 1;
} else {
    $x = 2;
}
```

Also there is a typo in you code of __set and __isset.

You should get an undefined variable warning because you wrote `->_parts` instead of `->parts` there.

Turn on display_errors and set the error_reporting to include `at least` E_NOTICE so you don't run into those problems without noticing. (In this case that doesn't help because __get and __set catch that call, but in general it's advice able)

Answer (score 1):

Guys thanks for the tips, indeed the underscore needed to go but the final solution was this:

$path = new RequestPath();

```
if(isset($path->foo)) {
    $x = 1;
} else {
    $x = 2;
}
```

Comment: You can edit your question, no need to create an "answer". If you problem is solved also please be so nice to accept an answer (using the checkmark) to let everyone know your problem is solved so people can go care about other questions :)